# How can I access the different properties of an API?

Tags: json, angular, rest, api

I have created a very simple JSON API. it has 3 properties, I can access and consume their values because I created it and I know what its properties are. But in case I'm using an API that I don't know what properties it has, and I wanted to, let's say, console log them ¿How can I iterate over API keys?

this is my API:

```
{
    "datum1" : [{
        "year": 2005,
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 18.1,
        "id":0
    }, {
        "year": 2006,
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 22.8,
        "id":1
    }, {
        "year": 2007,
        "income": 30.1,
        "expenses": 23.9,
        "id":2
    }, {
        "year": 2008,
        "income": 29.5,
        "expenses": 25.1,
        "id":3
    }, {
        "year": 2009,
        "income": 24.6,
        "expenses": 24.6,
        "id":4
    }],
    "datum2" :[{
        "year": 2005,
        "income": 33.5,
        "expenses": 38.1,
        "id":0
    }, {
        "year": 2006,
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 22.8,
        "id":1
    }, {
        "year": 2007,
        "income": 24.1,
        "expenses": 17.9,
        "id":2
    }, {
        "year": 2008,
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 27.1,
        "id":3
    }, {
        "year": 2009,
        "income": 28.6,
        "expenses": 24.3,
        "id":4
    }],
    "brands":["Hinata","Indra","Tobi","Guy"]
}
```

I'm serving it using json-server and consuming it from my angular app.

how can I print in console not the values of its keys (datum1, datum2, brands), but the keys itself?

I tried to perform a `for in` and `for of` after performing a get request to `https://localhost:3000`, hoping I was gonna get the whole JSON API, and then be able to console.log the keys, but I get 404.

I hope someone can understand this messy post and give me some clues.. Thanks.

Comment: if 404 then certainly its server issue else `Object.keys(your_object)` should do the work

Comment: I'll see the How to Ask. thanks, however, regarding to what you say that I didn't include any attempt to solve the problem: didn't you read this? "I tried to perform a `for in` and `for of` after performing a get request to https://localhost:3000".. of course it didn't work, but its an attempt. ¿Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to enumerate all API endpoints with just the domain name.
Like you want to make a request to `https://localhost:3000` and it should return a list of all API endpoints available in the server. If that is the case, it won't be available (unless there is a specific API endpoint configured to do this). If you are using a third-party API, it would generally have a documentation with all available endpoints and request methods.

Answer (score 1):

use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var data={
    "datum1" : [{
        "year": 2005,
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 18.1,
        "id":0
    }, {
        "year": 2006,
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 22.8,
        "id":1
    }, {
        "year": 2007,
        "income": 30.1,
        "expenses": 23.9,
        "id":2
    }, {
        "year": 2008,
        "income": 29.5,
        "expenses": 25.1,
        "id":3
    }, {
        "year": 2009,
        "income": 24.6,
        "expenses": 24.6,
        "id":4
    }],
    "datum2" :[{
        "year": 2005,
        "income": 33.5,
        "expenses": 38.1,
        "id":0
    }, {
        "year": 2006,
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 22.8,
        "id":1
    }, {
        "year": 2007,
        "income": 24.1,
        "expenses": 17.9,
        "id":2
    }, {
        "year": 2008,
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 27.1,
        "id":3
    }, {
        "year": 2009,
        "income": 28.6,
        "expenses": 24.3,
        "id":4
    }],
    "brands":["Hinata","Indra","Tobi","Guy"]
};


Object.keys(data).forEach(k=>{
console.log(k)
})
```

Comment: thanks buddy, but I'm trying to simulate I'm getting this from backend, in JSON format.  I would like to use `Object.keys` to the response of my get request, and my get request throws 404. It seems I cant perform get request to protocol/hosting/port, without specifying a more specific resource.

Comment: @JulioRodríguez [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404](404 means resource you are trying to access doesn't exist) check your endpoint or try to hit api using postmen and check if its working fine

Comment: thanks buddy. Look. my server that serves the API is upand running, if I, using postman or swagger or just the browser, try to acces to http:localhost:3000/datum1,

Answer (score 1):

if you crate a model for this and map it to than. than it is easy to access the key and values 
 https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/
this is a nice website to generate model from json